# How to execute commands or functions with increased privileges for sudousers

Tags: c, sudo, privileges, elevated-privileges, sudoers

In my client and server model, only root and sudousers has permissions to talk each other. Firstly, server authenticate client user(users on server), if any user other than root or sudousers then "permission denied message" is given backup to the client. But when client login as sudouser then it fails to execute certain commands which needs root privileges. but in case of root it works fine.

So,

```
 1) How to give sudouser privileges in c/c++ program if logged in user is 
    in sudousers list?
```

I tried to find out whether user is in sudousers list or not by command "sudo -v" and then if user is in sudouser I set the "userid" of the root rather than sudousers uid using "setuid()" system call. It worked but Does it is a right way to do the same?

Comment: Seems like `setuid` is the correct way to go. Anything else like `sudo` or the SUID mode bit require an executable be run for each user logged in.

Comment: Drew is correct. While you can change your sudoers (see: `visudo`) that will likely give the new nudo users greater privileges than necessary.